# Can't integrate mvcreportviewer with MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services

I'm having a difficult time utilizing ilich's mvcreportviewer nuget package with my MVC 4 application.  I am not sure where the problem lies but the error message i'm receiving is:

> *The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)*

I feel there could be a couple of places where i'm doing something wrong.  The first is that i might not be using the correct url to connect to SSRS.  In the example project provided on github the url was /TestReports/TestReport.  However, in a browser for my report the url looks like this:
http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTPSReports%2fTPSReport1&rs:Command=Render  Or i could also use:
http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTPSReports%2fTPSReport1

I have installed the nuget package and it created a MvcReportViewer.aspx page in my project along with an error page, .js file, and MvcReportViewer reference.  I have tried the following from the report View to open a SSRS report:

```
@Html.MvcReportViewer( "localhost%2fReports%2fPages%2fReport.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTPSReports%2fTPSReport1",
        new { Height = 900, Width = 900, style = "border: none" })
```

In the example the url was simply /TestReports/TestReport so i also tried:

- /Reports/TPSReport1
- /Reports/Pages/TPSReports/TPSReport1
- /Pages/TPSReports/TPSReport1

The SSRS is configured as:

- Web Service URL Virtual Directory = ReportServer
- Report Manager URL Virtual Directory = Reports
- Service Account = ReportServer
- Database Credentials use the ReportServer

I have also tried to download the report in a controller like this:

```
using MvcReportViewer;
private ActionResult DownloadTPSReport(ReportFormat format, string reportName)
    {
        return this.Report(
            format,
            reportName);
    }
```

The reportName variable is the url.  I tried all of the same ones as mentioned above.

I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.  I think the error message is misleading because the url is definitely less than 260 characters.

- Do i need to create a route in my MVC application for .aspx pages?
- Do i need to do anything in IIS?
- How can i determine what the real error is?

Thank You

Comment: Did you try to use `~/Reports/TPSReport1`?